# Django - load context data leaflet

Tags: javascript, django, geodjango

I've been working in a geodjango app to include a map for a search function in a spatial table, learning from tutorials, so far I know of a method to load serialized data in leaflet by creating a function based view assigning an url and importing that url as a GeoJSON.AJAX variable, I've been trying to change that method to then try to figure out a way to pass the data in my search function:

Views file:

```
def map_dide(request):
    return render(request, 'b_dide_uv/map_did.html')

def info_uvs(request):
    uv = serialize('geojson', D_uvs.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(uv, content_type='json')
```

Template:

```
 function uvs(map,options){
    var dataset = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'info_uvs' %}",{

    });
    dataset.addTo(map);
  }
```

I've been trying to insert the serializing and passing it as context in the map_dide function:

```
def map_dide(request):
    uv = serialize('geojson', D_uvs.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'b_dideco_uv/mapa_did.html', {'uv':uv})
```

but when I assign it in the javascript in the template it gives me an error, so far I tried:

```
  var uv_data = JSON.parse('{{uv|safe}}')
  function uvs(map,options){
    var dataset = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(uv_data,{
    });
    dataset.addTo(map);
  }
```

but I got an "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" in the console

I also tried the L.geoJson, and the L.GeoJSON function but it the same result

what others methods to insert serialized data in a template are there?, besides a separated function, in the case of a search function I asume it needs to be inside the same function to pass the result of the query, but it seems javascript doesnt recognize this data

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by installing [django-geojson](https://django-geojson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html#geojson-layer-view) library, changed how i set the data var in the javascript leaflet code:

views.py

```
def map_dide(request):
    uv = D_uvs.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'b_dideco_uv/mapa_did.html', {'uv':uv})
```

html

```
 var uv_data = {{ uv|geojsonfeature|safe }};
  function uvs(map,options){
    new L.geoJson(uv_data).addTo(map);
  }
```

Comment: I have the same problem.Can you share your url.py?

Comment: hi, I'm trying to remember, I added another comment, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

it seems that I finally made it work poping the "crs" from the geojson

views.py

```
feature:def mapa_dideco(request):
    uv_ini = serialize('geojson', D_uvs.objects.all())
    uv = json.loads(uv_ini)
    uv.pop('crs', None)
    uv = json.dumps(uv)
    return render(request, 'b_dideco_uv/mapa_did.html', {'uv':uv})
```

the rest remains the same